# Webkit transform plane in 3d disappears, doesn't seem like a back face issue. (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, 3d

Check this fiddle in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/resistdesign/Qvv2r/11/

The plane disappears for a few seconds. The back face is shown up to about 180 deg, then POOF!

I tried various configurations of `preserve-3d` and setting the back face visibility or not.

Kind of lost at this point :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWER!

The parent div has a `background-color`, at some point, **the rotating div is "behind" the parent**.

Simply remove the `background-color` of the parent and add it to an element "earlier" in the DOM.